# Excelscript: Iterate over table and pull data for matching rows

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office365, office-scripts

I'm attempting to create a for loop that checks Column "B" in Sheet "A" for the string "Yes". If true, then I want to copy the formula from Column "B" in Sheet "A" to Column "C" in Sheet "B".

So far I'm just generating the formula for Row 0. I'm not sure where to go from here. I've attached as much useful information as I can.

Any advice?

Pseudocode:

```
i = 0
for index of worksheet
  if index.string == "yes" then
    
    array.insert(CELLVALUE(SHEET:A_COLUMN:B[index]))
    copyArray to (SHEET:B_COLUMN:C[i])
    i = i + 1
```

````js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Your code here
    let fermLog = workbook.getWorksheet("Fermenter Log")
    let testing = workbook.getWorksheet("Testing")
    let autoFiller = testing.getRange("C4:C200")
    let fermLogSample = fermLog.getRange("E4:E2000")
    var sampleValues = fermLogSample.getValues()
    let fermLogTime = fermLog.getRange("B4:B2000")
    var timeFormula = fermLogTime.getFormula()
    var str = "Yes"
    for (var index of sampleValues) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
          if (index[i] == str) {
            console.log(fermLogTime.getCell(i, 0).getFormula())
          }
        }
      }
    }```

/// Only outputs row 0 because i is always defined as 0
````

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let desSht = workbook.getWorksheet("B")
    let desRange = desSht.getRange("E4:E200");
    let desFormulas = desRange.getFormulas();
    let srcSht = workbook.getWorksheet("A")
    let rngCol = srcSht.getRange("B4:B200")
    var srcFormulas = rngCol.getFormulas()
    var srcValues = rngCol.getValues();
    var keyStr = "Yes"
    for (let i = 0; i < srcValues.length; i++) {
        if (srcValues[i].toString() === keyStr){
            desFormulas[i] = srcFormulas[i]
        }
    }
    desRange.setFormulas(desFormulas);
}
```